# Print NominalDiffTime in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I have piece of code like this in my Haskell program:

```
...
start <- getCurrentTime
...
end <- getCurrentTime
...
delta = end `diffUTCTime` start
...
```

After this, `delta` has type `NominalDiffTime`. As written in the documentation, this type in inherited from `Num`, and I want to print it with 3 (for example) places after decimal dot. However, using something like `printf "%.3f" delta` doesn't work: `No instance for (PrintfArg NominalDiffTime)`.

How to do this correctly?

Comment: Note that `delta` isn't necessarily the time that elapsed between the two - `NominalDiffTime` ignores leap seconds, for example.

Comment: It's true, but I think it can be safely ignored in almost all programs.

Comment: Well, you *say* that, but it's depressing how many things broke last time there was an awkward leap second... a server I sysadmin for had to be rebooted *twice*, iirc.

Comment: If you're sufficiently unlucky, for example, I think `delta` could be negative... (or positive, or whichever it isn't supposed to be)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert it to a `PrintfArg` type to print it in the desired format, e.g.

```
printf "%.3f" (realToFrac delta :: Double)
```

does it.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a nicely formatted diff time, you can use `System.Time.Utils (renderSecs)` together with `round`

```
 ghci> import Data.Time.Clock
 ghci> import System.Time.Utils (renderSecs)
 ghci> 
 ghci> let renderS = renderSecs . round :: NominalDiffTime -> String
 ghci> t1 <- getCurrentTime
 ghci> -- wait a little :-P
 ghci> t2 <- getCurrentTime
 ghci> renderS $ t2 `diffUTCTime` t1
 "2m15s"
```

It will also do days as d, and hours as h. Note that the type signature is mandatory for ghci, because otherwise it'll default to `Double`, and suddenly you can't feed it `NominalDiffTime` values.

Comment: You don't need the type signature if you define it with an argument, `let renderS d = renderSecs (round d)`, or if you turn off the MR `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`.

Comment: Is it suitable only for printing whole number of seconds, or can be modified for fractional part too? I've tried to use `renderTD` from the same `System.Time.Utils`, but no luck.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yeah, that's possible, too. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @chersanya: no, look at the signature: `renderSecs :: Integer -> String`. I think you'd have to write your own pretty printing function to do that. You could also just use `renderSecs`, then subtract the integer amount from the `DiffTime` to get at the decimal part, then attach that to the render function. Ugly, I know, but besides reimplementing `renderTD` I don't see a way.